# ASP.NET MVC: Should I include DataContext files (.dbml and .dbml.layout) in the deployment package?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment

Should I include DataContext files (.dbml and .dbml.layout) in the deployment package?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4):

They represent source code (or technically, a step right before source-code) and is unused by asp.net (they are linq-to-sql files), so no, do not include them.